# How do I use a for loop to update an array's element at the i'th index?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to loop through an array and update the element at the i'th index. I've tried several ways but they've all resulted in an error.

Here I'm trying to increment each element by one.

```
TEST_ARR=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

for (( i=0; i<${#TEST_ARR[@]}; i++ )); do
    ${TEST_ARR[$i]}++
done
```

Here I'm trying to set each element to a different value.

```
TEST_ARR=(0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)

for (( i=0; i<${#TEST_ARR[@]}; i++ )); do
    ${TEST_ARR[$i]}=0
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put arithmetic expressions inside `(())`.

When you're assigning to a variable, you don't put `$` before it.

```
for (( i=0; i<${#TEST_ARR[@]}; i++ )); do
    ((TEST_ARR[$i]++))
done
```

```
for (( i=0; i<${#TEST_ARR[@]}; i++ )); do
    TEST_ARR[$i]=0
done
```

Comment: `$i` can also be just `i` since we're in an arithmetic context in both snippets.

Comment: A small note of caution regarding `((TEST_ARR[$i]++))` -- it will return a non-zero exit code if `TEST_ARR[$i]` is `0`. If the script is running with `set -e` this will cause it to error out and exit.

Comment: That's why `set -e` is almost never the right thing to use.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Is `let TEST_ARR[$i]++` better?

Comment: I didn't realize you needed to remove the $ for variable assignments to arrays. This worked, thank you!

Comment: `let` has the same problem. I'm not sure what the best fix is. I forget what I've used in the past -- `|| :`, maybe?

Comment: @SanbornNguyen You don't *need* to, you're *allowed* to.

Comment: With `let` lack of quoting can become an issue. If `set -e`, then do it as a variable assignment: `TEST_ARR[i]=$((TEST_ARR[i] + 1))`